# What is the average maximum number of pairs such that $x_i > y_i$ for uniformly distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X \sim U(a, b)$ and $Y \sim U(c, d)$ I would like to find average maximum number of pairs such that for $pair_i = (x_i, y_i): x_i > y_i$ when I have $n$ samples for $X$ and $n$ samples for $Y$.

Example:

$X$ is uniformly distributed between $1$ and $10$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed between $3$ and $11$. I draw $5$ samples for each random variable:

$$
X = [5, 7, 9, 3, 7] \qquad Y = [6, 9, 4, 8, 5]
$$

I could arrange it into pairs:

$$
pairs_a:(5, 6) \quad (7, 9) \quad (9,4) \quad (3,8) \quad (7,5)
$$

or another example:

$$
pairs_b:(9, 8) \quad (7, 6) \quad (7,5) \quad (5,4) \quad (3,9)
$$

Here $pairs_a$ gives me 2 pairs where $x_i > y_i$ but $pairs_b$ gives me 4 such pairs. In this example, the maximum number of pairs fulfilling my condition is 4 (nothing will be greater than $9$ coming from Y).